# SQL Server grant to multiple domains

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, architecture

I am working in a joint venture of four different contractors doing one big project. Many of the application will have to use the different ADFS servers each of the four companies have. Some are desktop application connecting directly to SQL which will be hosted in IaaS. Can SQL Server grant permissions to four different domains?

Comment: you're going to have to get creative here with SQL Users, a proxy server in front of the sql server, or move the domains in a forest and make trust relationships between them.

Comment: you mean reverse proxy? how would I go about doing that? I don't think they will want trust between the domains it's just a project not a merger :)

Comment: naw, a reverse proxy will help you traverse network level issues but not domain level issues.  Sadly in this case you might need to use SQL Server users and talk about it with your security team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB Links can be configured with different accounts for each DB Link. But it would still be an ugly mess as far as security and management.